# Microsoft Speech SDK: android library v1.8.0 missing native speech extension kws .so libs

Tags: android, sdk, client, azure-cognitive-services, speech

## Missing native speech extension kws .so files within published 'com.microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech:client-sdk:1.8.0' .aar

#### Android code Error message:

E/ unexpected java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception with an error code: 0x24 (**SPXERR_EXTENSION_LIBRARY_NOT_FOUND**)

#### Microsoft maven link

https://csspeechstorage.blob.core.windows.net/maven/com/microsoft/cognitiveservices/speech/client-sdk/1.8.0/client-sdk-1.8.0.aar

### Expected content:

REDIST.txt from .aar mentions following libraries

```
client-sdk-<VERSION>.aar (or content derived from it) 
client-sdk-<VERSION>.jar
libMicrosoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.core.a
libMicrosoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.core.dylib
libMicrosoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.core.so
libMicrosoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.extension.codec.so
**libMicrosoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.extension.kws.so**
libMicrosoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.java.bindings.**jnilib**
```

### Found:

**does not contain** marked library within corresponding jni ABI directories

```
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
META-INF/MSFTSIG.SF 
META-INF/MSFTSIG.RSA 
AndroidManifest.xml
classes.jar 

jni/arm64-v8a/
  libMicrosoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.core.so 
  libMicrosoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.extension.codec.so
  libMicrosoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.java.bindings.so

jni/armeabi-v7a/
  libMicrosoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.core.so
  libMicrosoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.extension.codec.so
  libMicrosoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.java.bindings.so

jni/x86/
  libMicrosoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.core.so
  libMicrosoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.extension.codec.so
  libMicrosoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.java.bindings.so

jni/x86_64/
  libMicrosoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.core.so
  libMicrosoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.extension.codec.so
  libMicrosoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.java.bindings.so

license.md
proguard.txt
R.txt
REDIST.txt
ThirdPartyNotices.md
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Speech SDK 1.9.0 release (estimated on middle of January 2020) will contain the support KWS extension inside .aar package.